# Flutter/Adonis server and Google auth

Tags: flutter, authentication, oauth, token, adonis.js

I have API server written with Adonis JS (it handles REST calls, auth, contain DB). When user login/register successful server return [opaque access token](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/api-tokens-guard).

I need to create Flutter App and it should use existing server. Also i need to add social authentication (google, twitter, facebook). I'm thinking of [creating user on my server](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/social) when social API return user credentials.

But i'm totally confused with the way it should work. How to initiate process of social login (from [app](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth) or from [server](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/social)?). Who should handle redirects/callbacks from auth app. How to handle case when created user login again with social app.

I will appreciate if someone can describe that process (general overview).

Thank you!